# Jquery custom callback not working, cannot find root issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using this tutorial: http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/

I made a simple callback function... however it is calling synchronously. Where am I going wrong? It's driving me nuts!

Expected behavior: the alert box and color change will wait until the animation is completed.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PCj5h/

```
$('#div1').click(function(){
    animate('#div1', function(){
       changeDiv2('#div2');
       alert('done'); 
    });   

});

function animate(div, callback){
    $(div).animate({left: '200px'}, {duration: 5000, queue: true});
    $(div).animate({top: '200px'}, {duration: 5000, queue: false});
    callback();   
}

function changeDiv2(div){
    $(div).css('color','#FF0000');    

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me. It may be a browser compatibility issue. Which browser are you using?

Comment: firefox and chrome... Are you using the fiddle I provided? I want the animation to occur first and then the alert (just to clarify).

Comment: What is the expected behavior? It looks like it's working fine in the fiddle: When I click "div1," it starts the animation, changes "div2" to red, shows an alert that says "done," and five seconds later the animation finishes.

Comment: I want to wait until the animation is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By 'synchronously', I think you mean 'the callback isn't waiting til the animation completes'. At least, that's what is happening on the fiddle on the latest Chromium build.

Try this to force the callback to wait for the animation to complete before firing: http://jsfiddle.net/EGCVy/

Modified code:

```
function animate(div, callback){
    $(div).animate({left: '200px'}, {duration: 5000, queue: true});
    $(div).animate({top: '200px'}, {duration: 5000, queue: false, complete: callback});
}
```

See [jQuery's `animate` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more information about the `complete` option (and other useful details!)

A Note: in computing 'synchronous' doesn't mean what [popular dictionaries](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synchronous) says it does. In essence, it means that you perform the operations in order. The alternative is 'asynchronous', where multiple things may happen at once. This is a bit of a simplified version. For a more in-depth answer, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean).

Comment: Okay, this answer is close to what I need- thank you! BUT what if the `animate(div, callback)` function has further logic that is beyond just the `$(div).animate()` and even the callback within the `$(div).animate()` is too soon? Sorry I know this is out of the bounds of my original question.

Comment: "Blocking" really means that no other computation will occur on the thread until it's finished, which isn't the case here (`animate` still returns immediately even though `callback` won't be executed until later). This is really a synchronous/asynchronous distinction, not blocking/non-blocking.

Comment: @user3311351 you would have to move the rest of the `animate()` function's functionality into a callback function. This could be an anonymous function (so you wouldn't need to clutter your code or namespace with single-use callback functions). At the end of this callback, you would call the original `callback` function.

Answer (score 0):

J. David Smith's answer is correct, but I wanted to point out that in jQuery you can simply this by using a single `$.animate` call instead of two. You can give several properties in the first argument.

```
function animate(div, callback) {
  $(div).animate(
    { left: '200px', top: '200px' },
    { duration: 5000, complete: callback }
  );
}
```